# Erro em página do CMS em Code Igniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, cms

Estou tendo um erro com um CMS desenvolvido por outra pessoa em CodeIgniter, o erro é o seguinte

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_instance() in /home/msinai/public_html/application/errors/error_404.php on line 1
```

**Detalhe:** Esta página é uma página de administração do CMS, portanto só deve ser mostrada quando logado, porém, qualquer pessoa pode ver o erro acessando:

http://www.meusonhodechacara.com.br/cms/andamentos/index

Sou MUITO leigo em programação back end, e tentei fazer umas modificações em alguns arquivos, que aparentemente foram bem sucedidas, não mexi nesse arquivo de erro 404 e este erro está aí. Segue o código da página error_404.php

```
<?php $ci =& get_instance(); ?>
<?php $ci->fixed_content->header(); ?>
<?php $settings = $ci->fixed_content->settings; ?>
<section class="pages contact" style="background-image: url(<?php echo upload_url($settings['banner']); ?>);">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Página não encontrada</h1>
        <div class="wrap">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
<?php $ci->fixed_content->footer(); ?>
```

Código da página do Controller desta página Andamentos:
http://pastebin.com/Py7Yf24U

Versão PHP: 5.3.29

Versão do CodeIgniter: 1

Simplesmente não se de onde saiu esse erro e nem como resolver, agradeço se me ajudarem. Obrigado.

Comment: A não ser que exista um mapeamento diferente, "**$this->load->view('andamentos', $this->data)**" do seu controller está chamando o script '**/application/views/andamentos/index.php**'. Esse script está onde deveria?

Comment: Sim, segue pastebin deste arquivo http://pastebin.com/mgDRJYr3

Comment: Seu controlador para bem aqui: **"if(empty($pagina)) show_404();"**. Ele nem está carregando a VIEW por causa desse erro. Verifique o motivo desse ARRAY estar vazio.

Comment: Pode me ajudar em como faço isso? Não manjo disso

Comment: Não manja PHP ou CodeIgniter? Olhe, eu creio que isso aqui: **$this->paginas->obter();** é um método (possivelmente de um model) tentando pegar valores com base no item de configuração **$this->fixed_content->settings['pagina_andamento']**. Mas de longe fica difícil... Vc vai ter que olhar com calma e descobrir o motivo dessa operação não ter funcionado deixando o array **$pagina** vazio e causando a parada do programa.

Comment: O erro que vc relatou na pergunta é gerado por `show_404();`, e ele só está sendo mostrado porque o array `$pagina` está vazio...